# dotnet --version is not working, but the SDK is installed by Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

- I tried searching the issue online, but found no exact issue I'm having or the fix for it

So I'm trying to verify what version of the .NET SDK I have installed. Obviously I run the `dotnet --version` command, but the results are unexpected. The command yields this message:

```
C:\Users\HP>dotnet --version
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
  * You intended to execute a .NET application:
      The application '--version' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/download

Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found

C:\Users\HP>
```

I did navigate to https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found, but didn't get useful information from there.

This is the PATH environment variable. I've removed paths to software that are irrelevant to the problem.

```
C:\Users\HP>echo %path%
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\HP\.dotnet\tools

C:\Users\HP>
```

Sounds like a simple fix - just install the .NET SDK. However, I have Visual Studio 2022 with the .NET Desktop Development workload installed. Visual Studio 2022 installs the .NET SDK for me. According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net80#install-with-visual-studio):

> Visual Studio can install the latest .NET SDK and runtime.

Also:

> - You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
>   No .NET SDKs were found.

As I explained earlier, Visual Studio did already install the SDK for me, yet it still outputs the message "No .NET SDKs were found.". I don't even know what version of the SDK I have installed.

So, what is even going on here? How can I fix the issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Fix the PATH, the c:\program files (x86) flavor should not be there.  Why the 32-bit version of dotnet.exe doesn't understand --version is not terribly obvious.  It doesn't promise it does however when you run it with -h

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, the solution solved the problem. Can you post an answer instead of a comment? I would mark it as accepted.